# how to Retrieve only particular column from Realm React native?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, realm

```
DBHelper.realm.objects(DBHelper.Test).filtered('Id == $0', 1)
```

Which return whole data set

```
{"0": {"Id": 1,"test1": 1,"test2": 1},"1": {"Id": 1,"test1": 2,"test2": 1}}
```

Interested Out put , test1 column set only

```
{ "0": { "test1": 1  }, "1": {  "test1": 2  } }
```

Comment: show, what you've tried so far. let's see if you're missing something or not.,

Comment: i have already written that i am using 
DBHelper.realm.objects(DBHelper.Test).filtered('Id == $0', 1)

which return whole table data set 

what i want is  
{ "0": { "test1": 1  }, "1": {  "test1": 2  } }


where DBHelper.Test is Table name

Answer (score 0):

You can DISTINCT and apply the map function

`DBHelper.realm.objects(DBHelper.Test)
.filtered("TRUEPREDICATE DISTINCT(test1)")
.map(item => {
   return { test1: item["test1"] };});`

may help you.